# react router getComponent passing pathvariable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/home.jsx';

const loadAsync = (promise) => (location, callback) => {
promise
    .then(module => callback(null, module.default))
    .catch(e => console.warn('Could not load route component', e));
}

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return(
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/hello/:foo" getComponent={loadAsync(System.import('./components/hello.jsx'))} />
        </Router>
    )
}
}

export default App;
```

My hello.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class Hello extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (<h1>Hello {this.props.matches.foo}!</h1>);
}
}

export default Hello;
```

The home.jsx contains a Link to "/hello/World".

How can read the "foo" variable in hello.jsx?
Do I have to pass it in loadAsync() and how ?

Comment: `this.props.params.foo`

Comment: you are welcome